# image attribute is undefined using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting console.log($(this).attr('src')) as undefined. I want to modify src attribute of all `img` 
  elements in loop.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#btn1").click(() => {

    $(".images").each(() => {
      console.log($(this).attr('src')); // getting undefined
      var srcText = $(this).attr('src');
      var srcArr = srcText.split('?').split('?');
      srcArr[srcArr.length - 1] = genRandQuery();
      $(this).attr('src', srcArr.join('?'));
    });

  });

  function genRandQuery() {
    return 'rnd=' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(7);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<img class="images" src="https://abc?rnd=1234">
<img class="images" src="https://abc?rnd=2354">
<img class="images" src="https://abc?rnd=9876">

<button id="btn1">Show Text</button>
```

Comment: Just replace `() => {` with `function() {`

Comment: there is not only context problem,split chains are incorrect. when done first split, it Will give you array and array does not have split method. therefore it also will throws error

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
       $(".images").each( function() { 
         const srcText = $(this).attr('src').split('?');
         const newSrc = `${srcText[0]}?${genRandQuery()}`;
          console.log(newSrc)
         $(this).attr('src', newSrc);
      });

    });

    function genRandQuery() {
      return 'rnd=' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(7);
    }

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="images" src="https://abc?rnd=1234">
<img class="images" src="https://abc?rnd=2354">
<img class="images" src="https://abc?rnd=9876">

<button id="btn1">Show Text</button>
```